# Compare pixel charts

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm using the following code to get the RGB color from a certain pixel location.

```
public Color GetColorAt(Point location)
{
    using (Graphics gdest = Graphics.FromImage(screenPixel))
    {
        using (Graphics gsrc = Graphics.FromHwnd(IntPtr.Zero))
        {
            IntPtr hSrcDC = gsrc.GetHdc();
            IntPtr hDC = gdest.GetHdc();
            int retval = BitBlt(hDC, 0, 0, 1, 1, hSrcDC, location.X, location.Y, (int)CopyPixelOperation.SourceCopy);
            gdest.ReleaseHdc();
            gsrc.ReleaseHdc();
        }
    }

    return screenPixel.GetPixel(0, 0);
}
```

But is there any way to save a chart of, for example, 10x10 pixels? My goal is to compare one chart to another and see if they are identical.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a method that copies the part of the screen into `Bitmap` of whatever size you want (assuming you are not creating bitmaps larger than the screen in which case you should check the size) like in the example:

```
public Bitmap GetPartOfTheScreen(Point location, Size size)
{
    Bitmap screenPartCopy = new Bitmap(size.Width, size.Height);
    using (Graphics gdest = Graphics.FromImage(screenPartCopy))
    {
        using (Graphics gsrc = Graphics.FromHwnd(IntPtr.Zero))
        {
            IntPtr hSrcDC = gsrc.GetHdc();
            IntPtr hDC = gdest.GetHdc();
            int retval = BitBlt(hDC, 0, 0, size.Width, size.Height, hSrcDC, location.X, location.Y, (int)CopyPixelOperation.SourceCopy);
            gdest.ReleaseHdc();
            gsrc.ReleaseHdc();
        }
    }

    return screenPartCopy;
}
```

When you get the part of the screen you could compare the pixel colors by using `GetPixel` (slow approach) or you could take advantage of the `LockBits` method of the Bitmap class to compare the pixels.

Comment: Thank you, looks just like what I need!